# impl Write cannot be sent between threads safely

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-safety

I want to exit [Termion](https://docs.rs/termion/latest/termion/raw/index.html)'s raw mode with `drop(stdout)` before exiting the process. But I'm doing it inside a spawned thread, and with `stdout` of type `&mut impl Write`, which produces this compile error:

```
impl Write cannot be sent between threads safely
required because it appears within the type &mut impl Write
```

This is a runnable simplified version of the code:

```
use std::{io::Write, time::Duration};

pub struct CmdRunner {}

impl CmdRunner {
    // there a `new()` method in the original code

    pub fn run(&mut self, stdout: &mut impl Write) {
        // code that runs the command

        let ctrl_c_pressed = false;

        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            if ctrl_c_pressed {
                // I want to use `drop(stdout)` here to exit Termion's raw mode.
                write!(stdout, "Exit raw mode").unwrap();           
                std::process::exit(0);
            }
        });

        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));

        write!(stdout, "Command executed successfully").unwrap();

        stdout.flush().unwrap();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cmd_runner = CmdRunner {};
    let mut stdout = Vec::new();
    
    cmd_runner.run(&mut stdout);

    println!("stdout: {:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&stdout).to_string());
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fdf7254df54ada1204ece4c9927db968)

Note: I tried this: `pub fn run(&mut self, stdout: &mut (impl Write + std::marker::Send))`

But that produces another error:

```
borrowed data escapes outside of method
stdout escapes the method body here
borrowed data escapes outside of method
argument requires that '1 must outlive 'static
```

Comment: Adding `+ Send` is the correct solution. The second error is unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well let's break the issues down.
The first issue says, that the object that gets sent to the thread needs to be sendable (it has to be `impl Send`, you can skip the `std::marker`). This is important, because types like `Rc` are not sendable since that could lead to undefined behaviour. You correctly demised that that means you have to restrict your generic to sendable types.

The second issue has to do with how rust handles lifetimes.
The borrow checker in rust has to know (at compile time) how long your objects will live and will check the lifetimes of these objects. Since you take in a reference to your runtime the compiler assigns am implicit lifetime to it which it calls `'1`. Now you want to send this to a thread. However the compiler cannot possibly know how the lifetime of the thread itself. Does the thread get executed right away? Does it get executed after your program is already finished? All that depends on the scheduler and is runtime dependent. Therefore the rust standard library places the restriction on threads that all references moved into them MUST be `'static` (or basically alive forever). Now your `stdout` definitely is not alive forever and placing the `&mut 'static ...` restriction on it would be stupid too. Therefore we need a way to have a way to keep track of the object lifetime at runtime. We do that using reference counting with the `std::sync::Arc` type (which does atomic or thread-safe reference counting). However data inside an `Arc` is immutable (since rust only allows one mutable reference to the data at a time, everything else is undefined). Therefore we need to enforce that one mutable reference restriction at compile time as well using something like a `Mutex`.

TL;DR The classing rust threading tip: Wrap your data into an `Arc<Mutex<_>>`

It should look a little something like this:

```rust
fn run<W: Write + Send>(&mut self, stdout: Arc<Mutex<W>>) {
    // Create a new instance of the Arc that we can move
    let stdout_clone = stdout.clone();
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
      let stdout = stdout_clone.lock();
      // ... do your other stuff
     });
    ///... more stuff
}
```

Be aware that this can lead to bad locking, so only lock your mutex when needed and drop the MutexLock as soon as its unneeded.

Comment: Thanks! I have one question: this way `stdout` will always have to be passed as a `Arc<Mutex<_>>` as an argument for `run()`? For example, I can't pass a `Vec<u8>` for testing purposes?

Comment: Well you can pass the Vec in directly using something like `run(&mut self, stdout impl Write+Sync+Send)` and then construct the Arc<Mutex<_>> inside the run function, but then you're *moving* the vector to the function and you cannot access it later in your main function. You cannot (safely) create an Arc<Mutex<>> from reference since that would violate the 1 owner rule.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the constrains on `W` there only needs `Send` and not `Sync`.   The `Mutex` will make the "whole thing" `Send + Sync`.  That's the idea: `Mutex` turns "just `Send`" into `Send + Sync`.  I think.

Comment: @KevinAnderson yep you're correct